# How to scrape paginated table with BeautifulSoup and store results in csv?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I want to scrape https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Reims.html and iterate through all and extract the results into `AircraftListing.csv`

The code runs without error, but the results are incorrectly populated and not all the records are extract from the webpage to the .csv file

How can I get out all  Reims aviation records to the AircraftListing.csv ?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

root_url = "https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Reims.html"
html = requests.get(root_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

paging = soup.find("table",{"class":"table table-bordered table-condensed"}).find_all("td")

start_page = paging[1].text
last_page = paging[len(paging)-2].text


outfile = open('AircraftListing.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Tail_Number", "Year_Maker_Model", "C_N","Engines", "Seats", "Location"])


pages = list(range(1,int(last_page)+1))
for page in pages:
    url = 'https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Reims:%s.html' %(page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    print ('https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Reims:%s' %(page))

    product_name_list = soup.find("table",{"class":"table table-bordered table-condensed"}).find_all("td")

    # Each row has 6 elements in it.
    # Loop through every sixth element. (The first element of each row)
    # Get all the other elements in the row by adding to index of the first.
    for i in range(int(len(product_name_list)/6)):
        Tail_Number = product_name_list[(i*6)].get_text('td')
        Year_Maker_Model = product_name_list[(i*6)+1].get_text('td')
        C_N = product_name_list[(i*6)+2].get_text('td')
        Engines = product_name_list[(i*6)+3].get_text('td')
        Seats = product_name_list[(i*6)+4].get_text('td')
        Location = product_name_list[(i*6)+5].get_text('td')

        writer.writerow([Tail_Number, Year_Maker_Model, C_N, Engines, Seats, Location])

outfile.close()
print ('Done')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve your code, especially the part with the for loop, try to select more specifically. Instead of the `<td>` select the `<tr>`, this minimises the effort you put into iterating and is more generic.

```
for row in soup.select('table tbody tr'):
    writer.writerow([c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('td')])
```

#### Example

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Reims.html'

with open('AircraftListing.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Tail_Number", "Year_Maker_Model", "C_N","Engines", "Seats", "Location"])

    while True:
        html = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        for row in soup.select('table tbody tr'):
            writer.writerow([c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('td')])


        if soup.select_one('li.active + li a'):
            url = soup.select_one('li.active + li a')['href']
        else:
            break
```

#### Output

```
Tail Number,Year Maker Model,C/N,Engines,Seats,Location
0008,1987 Reims F406 Caravan II,F406-0008,2,14.0,France
0010,1987 Reims F406 Caravan II,F406-0010,2,12.0,France
13701,0000 Reims FTB337G,0002,2,4.0,Portugal
13705,0000 Reims FTB337G,0016,2,4.0,Portugal
13710,0000 Reims FTB337G,0011,2,4.0,Portugal
...,...,...,...,...,...
ZS-OHP,0000 Reims FR172J Reims Rocket,0496,1,4.0,South Africa
ZS-OTT,1989 Reims F406 Caravan II,F406-0040,2,12.0,South Africa
ZS-OXS,0000 Reims FR172J Reims Rocket,0418,1,4.0,South Africa
ZS-SSC,1988 Reims BPSW,F406-0032,2,12.0,South Africa
ZS-SSE,1990 Reims F406 Caravan II,F406-0043,2,12.0,South Africa
```

#### Alternative with pandas

An alternative approach iterating over all 51 pages would be to use `pandas.read_html` to get the tables, append them to a list, `concat()` the dataframes from all the pages and save them as csv file including all 5085 records.

#### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Reims.html'

data = []

while True:
    #print(url)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    data.append(pd.read_html(soup.select_one('table').prettify())[0])

    if soup.select_one('li.active + li a[href]'):
        url = soup.select_one('li.active + li a')['href']
    else:
        break
df = pd.concat(data)
df.to_csv('AircraftListing.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: HedgeHog, Thank you.  You humbled me with how efficient the code  is.  I'm impressed!  I guess your code could pull out all the manufacturer data in one go.                                                    From airport-data.com/manuf/09.html                                          To      airport-data.com/manuf/Z.html

Comment: Happy to support - Humbled? Then nothing should stop an upvote. With an adjustment it would be quite possible to do this. However, you should first try it yourself and if you really get stuck, just [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exactly this focus. SO will take notice and support you. It's all about learning and I'm sure you can do that. A tip - the construct can be nested and provides you with the data.

Comment: Dear HedgeHog, respecting international languages the correct python code to use is  --->df.to_csv('AircraftListing.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do this but in lines 32-40 use:

```
# Each row has 6 elements in it.
# Loop through every sixth element. (The first element of each row)
# Get all the other elements in the row by adding to index of the first.
for i in range(int(len(product_name_list)/6)):
    Tail_Number = product_name_list[(i*6)].get_text('td')
    Year_Maker_Model = product_name_list[(i*6)+1].get_text('td')
    C_N = product_name_list[(i*6)+2].get_text('td')
    Engines = product_name_list[(i*6)+3].get_text('td')
    Seats = product_name_list[(i*6)+4].get_text('td')
    Location = product_name_list[(i*6)+5].get_text('td')

    writer.writerow([Tail_Number, Year_Maker_Model, C_N, Engines, Seats, Location])
```

The comments explain what is going on.

Comment: Thank you and reflected your recommendation in the original posting.  The .csv output is organised now but there are only 200 records out of 5085.   I want capture all of them and the last record in on https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Reims:51.html